# PHP and GD: PNG-24 transparency problem

Tags: php, gd

I have this code for placing a transparent PNG image watermark on photos. It works fine as long as the watermark img is PNG-8 (but looks ugly with anti-aliased images). If I use PNG-24, the watermark image looks fine, but loses transparency. Any way to fix it? Thanks.

CODE:

```
header('content-type: image/jpeg');  

$watermark = imagecreatefrompng('wm1.png');  
$watermark_width = imagesx($watermark);  
$watermark_height = imagesy($watermark); 

imagealphablending($watermark, true);
imagesavealpha($watermark, true);
$image = imagecreatetruecolor($watermark_width, $watermark_height);  

$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('image1.jpg');  
$size = getimagesize('image1.jpg');  
$dest_x = $size[0] - $watermark_width - 5;  
$dest_y = $size[1] - $watermark_height - 5;  


imagecopymerge($image, $watermark, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height, 100);  
imagejpeg($image, null, 95);  
imagedestroy($image);  
imagedestroy($watermark);
```

Comment: I starred this post, to check on it when I get home. I worked with `gd` before and had this problem as well. I fixed it but I have to check on the script, can't recall how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PNG 24 does not have a transparency layer, it just has 3 bytes representing Red Green and Blue. You should be using PNG 32 if possible as it has the alpha layer that you want.

Check out this link to see what I mean: http://www.deepbluesky.com/blog/-/the-difference-between-png24-and-png32_49/

as a Side note, this line of code in your program does nothing as `$image` is clobbered on the very next line:

```
$image = imagecreatetruecolor($watermark_width, $watermark_height);
```

Comment: As well, doing `$size = getimagesize('image1.jpg');` right after the imagecreatefromjpeg is redundant. getimagesize doesn't use GD, so it's loading the image again, parseing it again, etc... use imagesx() and imagesy() to get the native GD size info.

Comment: @ohmusama: that line does do something.  It leaks memory and resources, since the image resource won't be closed until the end of the script execution... :-D

Comment: Very true, since imagedestroy($image) is never called before the next one is allocated, but the statement was given to help him remove that line of code from his source. =P

As a side note, this is one of the few ways to cause a php script to have a memory leak. Strangely similar to c# <_<